# Need to read Nested Json and parse it in two columns (Id, newId) using dataframe in scala

Tags: json, scala, parsing, nested, multiple-columns

Here is sample data that needs to be divided into two specific columns

`{
  "tags": [
    {
      "1": "NpProgressBarTag",
      "2": "userPath",
      "3": "screen",
      "4": 6,
      "12": 9,
      "13": "buttonName",
      "16": 0,
      "17": 10,
      "18": 5,
      "19": 6,
      "20": 1,
      "35": 1,
      "36": 1,
      "37": 4,
      "38": 0
     },{
      "1": "Progression",
      "2": "Path",
      "3": "Light",
      "4": 10,
      "12": 5,
      "13": "TagName"
   }
 ]
}`

The output should look like

```
id    newid 
1     NpProgressBarTag
2     userpath
3     screen
4      6
12     9
13     buttonName
20      1

id     newId
1      Progression
2      path
3      Light
4      10
12     5
13     Tagname
```

Can anyone help me out with this issue.

Comment: The output should be in Id {all left elements}, in newId{all right elements} in a table format. thank you

Comment: Hi R, I'm not quite sure what you want your output to look like.  Do you want two columns named id and newId, and then one row per number?

Comment: @Jeremy Yes I need it in two columns id and newId.
Then id column consists of all left hand elements in json data ex: 1,2,3,4,12,13
and newId column consists of all right hand elements in json data ex: [NpProgressBarTag, userpath, ...]

Comment: One more question:  Do you want one row per element in the tags array, and each cell to contain an array?

Comment: @Jeremy 
If you can make it a table for each set in Json that would be appreciated or your method works good for me

Comment: I'm really sorry man, I can't figure out what you want :(

Comment: the schema should look like this 
`
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- newId: string (nullable = true) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one hard thing with your Data and that is that it contains `numbers` and `strings`.

My solution uses `play-json`!

So first I created a Structure to bring the Json into Scala-Land:

```
  case class Tags(tags: Seq[Map[String, String]])

  object Tags {

    implicit val mapReads: Reads[Map[String, String]] = { jv: JsValue =>
      JsSuccess(jv.as[Map[String, JsValue]].map {
        case (k, v) =>
          k -> v.toString
      })
    }

    implicit val jsonReads: Reads[Tags] = Json.reads[Tags]


  }
```

If you create a `case class` with this Reader `implicit val jsonReads: Reads[Tags] = Json.reads[Tags]`,

all that is missing is a Reader for the Map. This changes the generic `JsValue` to a String.

Usage:

```
json.validate[Tags] match {
    case JsSuccess(value, _) =>
      for{
        tags <- value.tags
        entry <- tags.toSeq
      } yield (entry._1, entry._2.toString)
    case err:JsError => // handleError
  }
```

Here essentially you flatten the Sequence and the Map.

The result is: `List((12,9), (19,6), (4,6), (37,4), (13,"buttonName"),..`

Here you can play with that yourself: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/kM6iBXF/2

Comment: Thank you for the response, this should help me

Comment: while compiling it says [not found value:object play]

`----
not found: object play
[error] import play.api.libs.json._
----
`

Comment: have you added the `play-json` dependency?

Comment: yes. I guess if I am not wrong this is the one you're talking about
`libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" % "play-json_2.11" % "2.5.2"`

Comment: yes - if you don't have a play project (then it is included) - to avoid the scala-version use: `"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.6.10"`

Comment: Yeah that worked but I got this error
----
`
No apply function found for TagDecode.Tags
[error]     implicit val jsonReads: Reads[Tags] = Json.reads[Tags]
[error]                                                     ^
[error] one error found`
----

Comment: just make sure you take the whole code from the scalafiddle example! as it works there;)